# \ifnum command with multiple conditions (lower and upper bound)

Tags: beamer, conditionals

First time posting here, very much a novice.

I'm creating some background templates in `beamer` and I can't figure out why this `\ifnum` command isn't working properly.

This is the code:

```
\setbeamertemplate{background}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle(\the\paperwidth,\the\paperheight);
\ifnum 1<\thepage<33\relax% Not the title page
    \fill[color=MedianOrange] (0,8) rectangle(0.8,8.3);
    \fill[color=MedianLightBlue] (0.9,8) rectangle(\the\paperwidth, 8.3);
\else% Title page
  \fill[color=MedianBrown] (0,1.2) rectangle (\the\paperwidth,\the\paperheight);
  \fill[color=MedianOrange] (0,0.1) rectangle(3.15,1.1);
  \fill[color=MedianLightBlue] (3.3,0.1) rectangle(\the\paperwidth,1.1); 
\fi
\end{tikzpicture}
}
```

Basically all I want to do is recreate the background on the first page on all the subsequent pages after #32. However, this only creates the correct background on the first page, the background on pages 33,34,35...etc. are as pages 2-32.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! `\ifnum` only accept *one* test: `\ifnum 1<\thepage<33` will just test if `1<\thepage` and consider `<33` as part of the “true text”. By the way, `1<\value{page}` is better, because it doesn't depend on the current meaning of `\thepage` (which might not be a number).

Comment: @egreg: That's true, but also using `\value{page}` can not be considered 100% safe. One can always exploit `\setcounter{page}{1}` somewhere in the presentation (with bad effects of course).

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino Of course I'm assuming the value of `page` is not tampered with.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The primitive `\ifnum` accepts only a single test, it's not able to do

```
1 < \value{page} < 33
```

Thus you need to make in more steps:

```
\setbeamertemplate{background}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle(\the\paperwidth,\the\paperheight);
\ifnum \value{page}=1
  \fill[color=MedianBrown] (0,1.2) rectangle (\the\paperwidth,\the\paperheight);
  \fill[color=MedianOrange] (0,0.1) rectangle(3.15,1.1);
  \fill[color=MedianLightBlue] (3.3,0.1) rectangle(\the\paperwidth,1.1);
\else
  \ifnum\value{page}<33
    \fill[color=MedianOrange] (0,8) rectangle(0.8,8.3);
    \fill[color=MedianLightBlue] (0.9,8) rectangle(\the\paperwidth, 8.3);
  \else
    \fill[color=MedianBrown] (0,1.2) rectangle (\the\paperwidth,\the\paperheight);
    \fill[color=MedianOrange] (0,0.1) rectangle(3.15,1.1);
    \fill[color=MedianLightBlue] (3.3,0.1) rectangle(\the\paperwidth,1.1);
  \fi
\fi
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
```

Note that it's better to use `\value{page}` instead of `\thepage`, because the former refers to the “abstract” counter value, not to any representation thereof.

Answer (score 24):

Pgfmath offers also boolean compositions hence you can fall back to it and test the resulting boolean with `\ifnum`;

```
\setbeamertemplate{background}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle(\the\paperwidth,\the\paperheight);
\pgfmathparse{\value{page}<33 &&\value{page}>1?int(1):int(0)}
\ifnum\pgfmathresult>0\relax% Not the title page
    \fill[color=MedianOrange] (0,8) rectangle(0.8,8.3);
    \fill[color=MedianLightBlue] (0.9,8) rectangle(\the\paperwidth, 8.3);
\else% Title page
  \fill[color=MedianBrown] (0,1.2) rectangle (\the\paperwidth,\the\paperheight);
  \fill[color=MedianOrange] (0,0.1) rectangle(3.15,1.1);
  \fill[color=MedianLightBlue] (3.3,0.1) rectangle(\the\paperwidth,1.1); 
\fi
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
```