# When I use the tkz-fct to simplify fractions, I want to format so the negative is in front of a fraction

Tags: tkz-fct

I found a way to simplify fractions using the following code.  I would like to modify it so that if the resulting fraction is negative to have the negative displayed in front of the fraction.

```
\documentclass{exam}
   \usepackage{mathtools}%includes amsmath
   %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
   \usepackage{tkz-fct}%%must be loaded before tkz
   \newcommand*{\fracReducedTkz}[2]{\tkzReducFrac{#1}{#2}\ensuremath{\ifnum\tkzMathSecondResult=1
       \tkzMathFirstResult
       \else\ifnum\tkzMathSecondResult=-1
       \number\numexpr-1*\tkzMathFirstResult
       \else\ifnum\tkzMathSecondResult<0
       \frac{\number\numexpr-1*\tkzMathFirstResult}{\number\numexpr-1*\tkzMathSecondResult}
       \else
       \frac{\tkzMathFirstResult}{\tkzMathSecondResult}\fi\fi\fi}}%
   
   \usepackage{tikz}
   \begin{document}
   \[\fracReducedTkz{-3}{4}\]
   
   \[\fracReducedTkz{3}{-4}\]
   
   %%This is how I would like to see it displayed
   \[-\frac{3}{4}\]
   \end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I have the mathematics fully correct, but I made three modifications to your code:

1. For the case where `\tkzMathSecondResult<0` I put a `-` before the `\frac` and removed the multiplication with -1 from the first argument of `\frac`
2. I added an `\else` for the case that `\tkzMathFirstResult<0` with a `-` before the `\frac` and with the first argument multiplied by -1 (and the second left as it is)
3. I added an extra `\fi` at the end to close the extra `\else` that was introduced

```
\documentclass{exam}
   \usepackage{mathtools}%includes amsmath
   %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
   \usepackage{tkz-fct}%%must be loaded before tkz
   \newcommand*{\fracReducedTkz}[2]{\tkzReducFrac{#1}{#2}\ensuremath{\ifnum\tkzMathSecondResult=1
       \tkzMathFirstResult
       \else\ifnum\tkzMathSecondResult=-1
       \number\numexpr-1*\tkzMathFirstResult
       \else\ifnum\tkzMathSecondResult<0
       -\frac{\tkzMathFirstResult}{\number\numexpr-1*\tkzMathSecondResult}
       \else\ifnum\tkzMathFirstResult<0
       -\frac{\number\numexpr-1*\tkzMathFirstResult}{\tkzMathSecondResult}
       \else
       \frac{\tkzMathFirstResult}{\tkzMathSecondResult}\fi\fi\fi\fi}}%
   
   \usepackage{tikz}
   \begin{document}
   \[\fracReducedTkz{-3}{4}\]
   
   \[\fracReducedTkz{3}{-4}\]
   
   %%This is how I would like to see it displayed
   \[-\frac{3}{4}\]
   \end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: any ideas for how to simplify when both are negative?  it seems to throw two negatives in there which is mathematically correct but not visually.

Comment: @E.Yu using the `\ifnum\else\fi` construct you can add all the cases that you want and print the output accordingly, similar to what I did in this answer. `\ifnum` itself does not have an AND operator so you either need to nest the if's or borrow from pgfmath, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/187999/ifnum-command-with-multiple-conditions-lower-and-upper-bound.